# #1044 - Access denied for user 'faiskap'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'

Tags: mysql

I am getting the following error on my database.

```
#1044 - Access denied for user 'faiskap'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

On 1044, I have the following code,

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `GLOBAL_STATUS` (
  `VARIABLE_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `VARIABLE_VALUE` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Please guide me how can I remove this error?

Comment: Your credentials are incorrect, or that user does not have the proper permissions, simple as that.

Comment: credentials ??????????????

Comment: Your username/password is incorrect, or 'faiskap@localhost' does not have the correct permissions to create a temporary table.

Comment: All privileges are given. I checked.

Comment: What was the default database when you performed that `CREATE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not `CREATE` *anything* in the databases `information_schema` or `mysql` or `performance_schema`.

`USE your_database_name` before executing that `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`.

Comment: even though your answer might be correct in this case, however it is not helping to solve the actual problem. I'm trying to remove a foreign key by running `alter table ... drop constraint` in my own database, which happens to be saved in information_schema by phpmyadmin that for some absurd reason seems to have more privileges than me!

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have global privileges

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'faiskap'@'localhost';
```

If not grant privileges

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'faiskap'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON *.* TO 'faiskap'@'localhost';
```

**The information_schema is a logical database, and you should not import or export information_schema. You must skip importing information_schema by giving --force option to mysql client if you are using old version of mysqldump**

Comment: All privileges are granted. I just checked.

Comment: I have a ready website on a different website. I am moving the website to another place.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem. My new hosting allows the user to only work in the database that he has created. The script is creating another database which is causing the error. I will manually create the database and run the script again.

Comment: What do I do then? I tried again and removed the information_schema from the database but the error is still coming.

Comment: There are no lines having the word, "information_schema" in them.

Comment: Foreign keys and check constraints are stored in information_schema regardless of the database or table that they belong to. for having a correct database structure sometimes it is required to have those included too. anyway, user is correct, I'm getting this error when trying to alter table in my own database and drop a FK constraint, and getting this error. even though the information_schema directly is not used in the script, some commands actually using it.